# Dictionary dilemma: Array vs Arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, arraylist

What I want to know is which one would be more efficient, should I use a 1D array and list 100 words, or make an array list to do the same thing in Java?

Note: I've only used arrays so far, array lists would be slightly new to me, I know what it is, I just have never used it before, also they would be used to randomly select a word.

Comment: What is your requirements?

Comment: Are you expecting to have the list of words grow at any given moment then your only option would be to go for the ArrayList. If you'd store a lot of integers then I would say a "normal" array, but since you're not, I'd again say go with the ArrayList.

Comment: Do you know you will never have more than 100 words? Are the words loaded up-front?

Answer (score 2):

If you know from the beginning the final number of elements then there is no point of using an ArrayList over an Array.  ArrayList are dynamical: they can grow but you have a small price to pay for it in term of performance and memory space requirement.  The difference is slim but if you don't need the autogrow feature of `ArrayList` then why asking for it?

However, beside that, there is anoter criteria that can make (or not) a bigger splash: Arrays are covariant where ArrayList are not; that is: if B is a subclass of A than a reference to an Array of A can also accept a reference to an array of B but a reference to an ArrayList of A cannot accept an ArrayList of B.  In other words, an Array of B will be considered as a covariant for an Array of A but an ArrayList of A won't:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}

A[] a = new B[1];  // OK
ArrayList<A> a2 = new ArrayList<B>();  // Error.
```

To circumvent this last error, you can try with a family of types such as:

```
ArrayList<? extends A> a3 = new ArrayList<B>();
```

but then, you are limiting the contravariance of the ArrayList a3:

```
a3.add(new A());  // Error!
a3.add(new B());  // Error again!
```

However, when you have an hierarchy of classes, it's usually a better idea to keep working with the superclass.  Therefore, even when you have a set of objects B where B is a subclass of A, keeping A[] and ArrayList instead of B[] and ArrayList for keeping references to these objects B is often better suited to OOP and easier to work with.

Sometimes, you may have to make a cast from A to B in order to access a property or a method of B which is not accessible from A.  However, this could be considered as a weakness in the design. OOP works best when you use the polymorphism at its fullest extent and the base class (or super class) should have all the necessary virtual functions to access the properties and methods of all subclasses and therefore you should be able to keep a reference to a subclass using the base class without having to make any cast thereafter.

Comment: But I must admit that if B is a subclass of A, keeping using A[] or ArrayList<A> for keeping reference to an array of objects B might be an even better idea than worrying oneself about covariance and contravariance.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `List`, there is almost no such difference between array and list on performance based.

But in case of `List` your code will easy to manage and flexible as comparing to array.

Answer (score 0):

If efficiency is your biggest worry here, then you have no worries. Use whichever you want. You'll see no appreciable difference in performance between an array and a List for 99.99% (completely made up) of applications. In general Lists are preferred over arrays because they're easier to work with.

Comment: So let's say I want to write up a dictionary of several words. If I were to randomly pull one out would it be easier with an Arraylist or Array. Currently I'm using an Array and using an int variable to randomly pick a word. Would it easier on the code if I chose Arraylist instead?

Comment: Again: you're worrying over nothing. Array: `String[] strings = ...; String s = strings[12];`. List: `List<String> strings = ...; String s = strings.get(12);`. Just go with what works for you.